# htaccess redirect rules chain priorities

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

A few years ago I redirected all my wordpress urls from this

```
/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/[TITLE]
```

to

```
/blog/[TITLE]
```

Now I removed the /blog/ so that I redirect all my urls from this

```
/blog/[TITLE]
```

to

```
/[TITLE]
```

That work's great. But here is the problem:

Now these urls

```
/blog/YYYY/MM/DD/[TITLE]
```

redirect to

```
/YYYY/MM/DD/[TITLE]
```

Result: 404

Here are my redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /blog/$4

RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog[/]?$
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=301,L]
```

How do I fix this? Any idea? To be honest: I never really understood how this works. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use chaining request without usage 301 redirect to the user until it's not resolved internally with apache rewrite rules. And only the latest request is exposed to the user with 301 redirect rule.

```
# Redirect to site without www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect /blog/YYYY/MM/DD/[TITLE] -> /blog/[TITLE]
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /blog/$4 [NC]
# continue chain, redirect /blog/[TITLE] -> /[TITLE]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: There is no error, redirect /blog/YYYY/MM/DD/[TITLE] -> /blog/[TITLE] is performed internally by apache without sending a result to the end user. If you want to expose redirect outside, replace flags [NC] to [NC,L,R=301], but, anyway in the next request there will be redirect to /[TITLE].

Comment: You were right. It was a problem with my browsers cache. It works. Thank you again!